# Price payed for the products column

Tags: google-sheets, mathematical-optimization, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have been pass all day into this and I couldn't find any solution to solve my problem.

I have a sheet, something like: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M1yj_FC_dGOjRxQv-Z-toE-niL_o3XkGEch6mGlebNg/edit?usp=sharing

I need one way to populate the `BUY PRICE` column, with the price paid for the product.

The operations are ordered by date (I use an ID to simplify).

Basically the D3 cell, needs be filled with $10 price. Because the store has 3 in stock.

D9 cell needs to be filled with $20 price because in the first purchase of the B PRODUCT I pay $ 15 per one unity, and sometime later, I buy more two per $25 (line six).

If I was seller just one product B, the unit price has been $15, but, I sell two B products on line 8, so, I need to calculate the average of my unity values ables in my stock.

I tried to resolve it using the `FILTER` function but doesn't work.

```
=IF(
        $C2="SELL";
                FILTER(
                        $F$2:$F;
                        $A$2:$A<=$A2;
                        $B$2:$B=$B2
                );
        "-"
)
```

It is like an assigned problem. but I couldn't find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(C2="SELL", AVERAGE(QUERY({INDIRECT("A1:C"&ROW()),INDIRECT("E1:G"&ROW())}, 
 "select Col5 where Col2='"&B2&"' and Col3='BUY' limit "&E2&"offset "&
 SUMIFS(INDIRECT("E1:E"&ROW()-1), 
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()-1), B2, INDIRECT("C1:C"&ROW()-1), "=SELL"), 0)), "-")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Now I could simplify the formula in my main project: `=IF($C7="VENDA";AVERAGE(QUERY($A$2:$S6;"select P where C='COMPRA' and A='"&$A7&"' limit "&G7&" offset "&(SUMIFS($G$2:$G6;$C$2:$C6;"COMPRA";$A$2:$A6;$A7)-(SUMIFS($G$2:$G6;$C$2:$C6;"VENDA";$A$2:$A6;$A7)+$G7));0));"-")`